# C++ std::string append overwrites instead of appending

Tags: c++, linux, string, file, append

I have over 80 levels for my game and only one fails the salted sha1 hashing. The reason is salt is being added inside the level file instead of end of it.

The problem occurs only in Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit, works in Windows. It happens at every launch and being inserted to the same position every time.

Level file is 2 lines, first line is the level file and second line is the hash. So I get the first line and append salt to it. But problem is still same with single line file too.

Here is the minimized code:

```
int main() {
    std::ifstream inf("level.txt");
    std::string lvl_file;
    std::getline(inf, lvl_file);
    inf.close();

    lvl_file += "MYSECRETSALT"; // lvl_file.append(..) also has same issue
    std::cout << lvl_file << std::endl;
}
```

This code prints the whole level file but MYSECRETSALT gets inside of it not to the end of it. If I print the lvl_file before appending, it prints nicely without missing anything.

```
// IT SHOULD BE LIKE
...[0,26],[1,61]],"decor_2":[[0,25000]],"decor_3":[[0,25000]],"tiles_3":[[0,25000]]},"ghosts":[],"turrets":[]}MYSECRETSALT

// BUT IT PRINTS LIKE THIS
...[0,26],[1,61]],"decor_2":[[0,25000]],"decorMYSECRETSALT0]],"tiles_3":[[0,25000]]},"ghosts":[],"turrets":[]}
```

Level file is at bottom of this: https://hastebin.com/ayeduwucid.php

Hardcoding the file into stringstream works normally though.

```
    std::stringstream inf;
    inf << R"json(..)json";
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem. Which compiler are you using

Comment: This is almost a good MCVE but you need to abstract the input too. Make it so that this a question that will help other visitors in the future.

Comment: g++ (Ubuntu 6.2.0-3ubuntu11~16.04) 6.2.0 20160901

I can't change the input because all the other levels work nicely as I said. Only this one has the problem, but not on Windows.

Comment: @naezith tried on ubuntu 16.04 and also have the same compiler version, still cannot reproduce the preoblem. Got the output as it should be (MYSECRETSALT is printed at the last after the whole file contents). I think you should try to run he minimal code you provided and see if the problem still presists

Comment: Cannot reproduce either (lubuntu 16.04, GCC 5.4.0) - by the way: the salt string is not inserted, but seems to *overwrite* part of the previously contained string.

Comment: Minimized the code a bit.

Comment: Just tried a stringstream and hardcoding the file as inf << R"json(..)json"; it works. So it it the ifstream?

Comment: I'm getting this same issue. Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit. (Technically Xubuntu). Essentially all my string concatenations and appends work just fine. Until I get to one append in particular.    insert.append("');\n\n");  At which it '); overwrites the first 3 characters of the same line.

Comment: g++ 5.4.0, so maybe the issue lies there, or it's some version of a dynamic library that g++ is currently linking to. Edit: I have the same issue with Clang 3.8.0-2ubuntu4. This is really frustrating, I have no clue what is going on.

Comment: The issue persists on g++ (Ubuntu 6.2.0-3ubuntu11~16.04) 6.2.0 20160901.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That file was written in Windows, and it goes to second line with `\n`. When I checked it in hex, it actually puts `\r\n` which leads these problems.